# Google Chrome: Manage Exceptions for Camera and Microphone

Tags: google-chrome

Trying to make an exception for a site to access my microphone and camera

`chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream` is not editable, is it normal? How do I add a rule?

Comment: Which site? ....

Comment: I need manually add an exception, how can I do it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, rules are manages by Chrome 1st then  plugins 2nd. First you need to allow the sites when Chrome points out and this happens through the top while bubble messages (like the one when going full screeen in a flash video).

Comment: Settings > Advanced > Privacy Content Settings > Media. Here, you need to select the allowed devices then tick allow requests for devices, there's a setting under manage as well for the same thing, doesn't sync with the main one. Flash player settings under Change are of no use here.

Comment: Once you get to the site in question there might be several inconveniences in getting to "Settings..." right-click menu of Flash. For instance, on midomi (song finder), the small flash player doesn't allow setup of own settings, only Global settings, so useless. I had to go to their mic test page and only then that test player allowed me to set up the mic properly. So you need to find the player in the site which shows you the "Settings..." option on right click menu, doesn't matter where, settings is done by whole domain and pick the devices, listing limited by Chrome.

Comment: @Ben Yanke: Thanks for trying to improve the site, but we try to avoid (1) putting the focus area of a question into the title ***when it is already in a tag**,* and (2) making trivial, cosmetic changes to posts that haven’t been changed in a long time (this one hasn’t had any activity in 2½ years).

Answer (score 1):

You add a rule by going to the site in question and then, if Media setting is "Ask when a site wants to use a plug-in to access your computer", it should prompt you for what to do - that will then get set as a specific exception.

You only use Manage Exceptions to remove existing exceptions.

See [Allow sites to access your camera and microphone](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en) and [Manage exceptions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?p=settings_manage_exceptions&rd=1)